# Shouldn't the SE quality check block posts that are only a link?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, low-quality-posts, quality-filter

I'm part of the MSE TAVERN ANTI-SPAM CLUB and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234172/proof-of-goldbachs-conjecture) <sup>*now deleted</sup> was just a link:

[image]

Just a link. The entire body of the post was within the outbound link. Can/should the SE quality check block these?

Comment: Very much related, possibly dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237848/anti-spam-blocking-questions-whose-bodies-end-with-a-raw-hyperlink.

Comment: @ShadowWizard There are many legitimate posts that end with a link. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16654133/1234256) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29617332/1234256) are good examples.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to what you are proposing, but I think you are using misleading language in your title and question.  I think it's misleading to call that "only a link" or "just a link".  It's clearly more than just a link: it has several lines of text.  I think it would be more accurate to classify this post as "all of the text is linkified" or "the entire text of the post is linked to a single URL".  "Just a link" would be if the entire body of the post was "`http://example.com/whatever`", with no English-language text.